# Is there any bound on all decreasing chain of closed subsets of a topological space?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Is there $N\in \mathbb{N}$ under which for every $\cdots \subset B_n \subset B_{n-1}\subset \cdots \subset B_2 \subset B_1$ of closed subsets of $X$ we have $B_i=B_{i+1}$ for all $i>N$?

Comment: This is clearly false in $\Bbb R$, take closed balls with the same center and decreasing radius. Or a countable discrete subspace and remove one point at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general topological space this is false as you can see for example with $\Bbb R$ and the subsets $D_n=\{x\mid \vert x \vert \leq 1/n\}$.

However, spaces which satisfy the condition *every descending chain of closed subsets stabilizes* are interesting. These [noetherian spaces](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noetherian_topological_space) appear in algebraic geometry for example.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space.
For $x \in X$ let $\mathfrak{U}(x)$ be the set of all open sets containing $x$.

The following are equivalent:

1. $X$ fulfills the condition of the question.
2. Each chain of open sets of $X$ is finite.
3. X is Alexandroff (i.e., each $x \in X$ has a smallest neighborhood) and the set $\{$ min $\mathfrak{U}(x): x \in X\}$ is finite.
4. $\tau$ is finite.

*Proof.*  $1 \Rightarrow 2$ and $4 \Rightarrow 1$ are obvious.  
$2 \Rightarrow 3$: By Zorn's lemma, $X$ is Alexandroff.
Let $\mathfrak{B} := \{$ min $\mathfrak{U}(x): x \in X\}$. Of course, each chain in $\mathfrak{B}$ is finite. But also each antichain $\mathfrak{A} \subset \mathfrak{B}$ (i.e. elements of $\mathfrak{A}$ are pairwise incomparable by "$\subset$") is finite: Since $X$ is noetherian, $\bigcup \mathfrak{A}$ is compact. Hence there is a finite subset $\mathfrak{A}^\prime$ of $\mathfrak{A}$ such that $\bigcup \mathfrak{A}^\prime = \bigcup \mathfrak{A}$. It follows $\mathfrak{A}^\prime = \mathfrak{A}$.
(Let $U=$ min $\mathfrak{U}(x) \in \mathfrak{A}$. Then there is a $V \in \mathfrak{A}^\prime$ containing $x$. Hence, by minimality of $U$, it is $U \subset V$, hence $U = V$, since $\mathfrak{A}$ is an antichain.)
Hence, by a well-known theorem about partially ordered sets, $\mathfrak{B}$ is finite, see, for instance, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96436/prove-that-for-any-infinite-poset-there-is-an-infinite-subset-which-is-either-li).

 $3 \Rightarrow 4$:
Since $X$ is Alexandroff, $\{$ min $\mathfrak{U}(x): x \in X\}$ is a basis for the topology. Hence $\tau$ is finite.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I overlooked that.